# Cannot assign values to multi-dimensional array in solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to use this function but I am getting an ambiguous error. All I get is `"errorCode":"32"`

Is there a reason this does not work? Am I missing something?

```
function generatePoints(uint256 pointsCount) public view returns (uint256[][1] memory) {
  uint256[][1] memory points;
  for(uint256 i; i < pointsCount; i++) {
    points[i][0] = 1;
  }

  return points;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work either

```
function _generateXPoints(uint256 pointsCount) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    uint256[] memory points;

    for(uint256 i; i < pointsCount; i++) {
      points[i] = 1
    }

    return points;
  }
```

Comment: The error seems unrelated to Solidity. The best I can think of is that some other tool returns the error 32 if the contract function reverted due to a runtime error, or maybe its not related to the contract at all... Can you show how you generate the call invoking the function? Are you running the contract on a blockchain emulator (which emulator) or on a live network accessing it through a node provider (which provider)?

Comment: I'm using hardhat to run my tests so I assume thats where the error is coming from. @PetrHejda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error code `0x32` is generated when you try accessing an array at an out-of-bounds index ([solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require)).

Indeed this dynamic memory array is created without allocating a length:

```js
// this will have zero length
uint256[] memory points;
```

Note that it is not possible to resize memory arrays ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays)), so the length must be specified during the declaration. In our case this should work:

```js
function _generateXPoints(uint256 pointsCount) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
    uint256[] memory points = new uint256[](pointsCount);

    for(uint256 i; i < pointsCount; i++) {
      points[i] = 1;
    }

    return points;
}
```

Returning to the multidimensional array. In solidity `uint256[x][y]` represents `y` arrays of length `x`. Also it's important to keep in mind that indices are accessed in the opposite direction of the declaration. So our array can be generated as:

```js
uint256[][1] memory points;
points[0] = new uint256[](pointsCount);
```

so by generating the "external" array first (length fixed to 1) and then the internal ones.
In conclusion:

```js
function generatePoints(uint256 pointsCount) public view returns (uint256[][1] memory) {
    uint256[][1] memory points;
    points[0] = new uint256[](pointsCount);
    for(uint256 i; i < pointsCount; i++) {
        points[0][i] = 1;
    }

    return points;
}
```

Comment: Amazing explanation. However, my question originally related to multidimensional arrays `uint256[][]` and not `uint256[]`. I think if we could expand on this to cover that use case as well, it would be an amazing help to the community and myself.

Comment: @bryan Thanks, I've edited to add the multi-dimensional solution, hope it helps!